# Installing linksys ac1200 drivers

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, because the wifi adapter doesn't work when I launch ubuntu I have the drivers downloaded on a USB drive from this source "https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux". I downloaded the drivers with a computer running Windows and installed them on a USB stick. How would I install them?

After running lsusb my adapter does show up

Comment: Providing your release details is the best way to start. Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stacks, so for some hardware, just switching stacks can be an easy fix. Instructions were provided on the link you provided for some release, but you didn't provide any release details.

Comment: Before we proceed, let's identify your exact device. Please edit your question to show the exact result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I don’t have lsub installed and I can’t install dkms either, I’m running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Not `lsub` but `lsusb` Please try again.

Comment: The adapter shows up when I run lsusb

Comment: So please [edit] the question and add the full relevant line identifying your device, as asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have someone who has Ubuntu with wifi, You can ask them to compile the file for you.

As you wrote you have a running Windows computer so they can send you the compiled files for the Github link you had sent. After that, you will put the compiled files onto your Ubuntu device (via USB), and after type the command in
"sudo modprobe -a rtl8812au"

Goodluck on your journey with Ubuntu!

Comment: wow!, thanks it worked. Although i had to get some help due to some errors at the end i was able to get it working, also nice kayne profile pic I like his music